# Why do does echo $var have a different number of output characters than ${#var} expands to?

Tags: bash

Hi I'm trying to learn bash scripting and I just want to get the character count of a variable.  I tried to do it using these two different methods, but I can't understand why I get a difference of one character? Thanks for the help.

chars="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

echo ${#chars} 
echo $(echo "$chars" | wc -c)

26
27

Comment: `echo` appends a newline unless invoked with `-n`, thus one more character

Comment: There's no need for a command substitution in the second. Just use `echo "$chars" | wc -c`; all you are doing is capturing standard output from `wc` in order to immediately write it back to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Within parentheses you wrote

```
echo "$chars" | wc -c
```

You want

```
echo -n "$chars" | wc -c
```

The `-n` suppresses trailing newline.
As it stands, you are writing one additional character after
the 26 letters, and `wc` is faithfully counting it.

---

Try this to see the effect of the `-n` flag.

```bash
echo -n abc; echo -n def
echo    uvw; echo    xyz
```

Comment: `echo -n` isn't POSIX-defined to do anything at all. `printf '%s' "$chars" | wc -c` is the better form.

Comment: (`-n` is the _only_ thing `echo` is allowed to treat as an option; any copy of `echo` that treats `echo -e` as an instruction to do anything other than print `-e` on output is noncompliant; and bash's echo can be configured to be more strictly standards-compliant in this respect; but while `-n` is allowed, it isn't defined by the standard to have any particular behavior).

Comment: Anyhow, _in bash_, run `set -o posix; shopt -s xpg_echo; echo -n` and you'll see `-n` written as output, not parsed as an option. Using `set -o` and `shopt -s` aren't the only way to get those options to be active -- they can be enabled through environment variables, or set as defaults at compile time, or in the `set -o posix` case enabled by starting the shell under the `sh` name.